# Indepth understanding of hash of sets in Python

Tags: python, hash, set, time-complexity

I have looked at many other posts such as
[How is set() implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949310/how-is-set-implemented) 
and [What does hash do in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585730/what-does-hash-do-in-python)
and I would like some clarification of my understanding. So far sets use a hashtable, with the key as a member of the set. So lets say I had

```
set1 = {'s','t','v'}
's' in set1
```

returns true, but how this is done to my understanding everything in set1 has had a hash, so for example the dictionary could be `dict['s'] = true`, and to see if 's' in set1 is like checking `dict['s']` and seeing if it is true or not. But my confusion comes from the fact that `'s'` will always have the same hash, which means if I had 2 sets, if `set1` hashed `'s'` to being true, how does `set2` hash `'s'` differently? Does every set have its own special hash function?

```
set1 = {'s','t'}
print('x' in set1)
print('s' in set1)
set2 = {'s'}
print('s' in set2)
```

Does `set2` and `set1` have different hashes for `'s'` when they are using the key as `'s'`.

Comment: No, the hash is the same. They are simply two separate hash tables.

Comment: Why do you think `s` needs two different hashes?

Comment: *attempts to thumbs up comment*, thanks :D

Comment: I thought that they went to the same hashtable :?

Comment: You can view hashes using the built-in `hash()` function; same string always returns same hash code. However `set1` and `set2` are different hashtables, different variables.

Comment: If you can read C you should take a look at the source for `set` and `dict`, which are really very similar. A set is essentially a `dict` with keys but no values. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c and https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c

Comment: I cannot read C, but what do you mean by keys with no values? Wouldnt you want to change the value from lets say, false to true, true meaning its in the set when checking the hashtable?

Comment: @MichaelCowie You don't need `false`, because the element simply doesn't exist in the set.