# Comparing lists within two lists for a match in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I have two lists. Each list contains a list containing a list of two point values, and a float value that is associated with those points.

ex.
list one [index 0]: 
`[[dt.Point([43.61, 24.88, -37.41]), dt.Point([42.33, 21.59, -31.28])], 10.0]` etc. 
list two: same format.

I am trying to compare the point values between the two lists for an exact match 
(meaning `list1[0][0] == list2[0][0]`)
 -thanks for any help

Comment: Consider using a dict to index one of the lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of thing you might want to make a simple class with a custom hash method so you can spot identical values. That way you don't have to get into the messy business of comparing all the values against each other.  Once you can hash the unique combination of two points and a value, you just make two sets of your lists and intersect them.

A basic example would look something like this (with openMaya MVectors instead of pymel points -- but the idea's the same)

```
from maya.api.OpenMaya import MVector

class PointHash(object):

    def __init__(self, p1, p2, v):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.value = v
        self._hashvalue = hash((p1.x, p1.y, p1.z, p2.x, p2.y, p2.z, v))

    def __hash__(self):
        return self._hashvalue

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return hash(self) == hash(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "PointHash %i" % self.__hash__()


#sample data
a = MVector(1.1, 2.2, 3.3)
b = MVector(1.0009, 2.00019, 3.0001)
c = MVector(21.0, 22.0, 23.0)


# some lists
set_one = set((PointHash(a, b, 1.0), PointHash(b, a, 1.0), PointHash(a, b, 2.0), PointHash(b, c, 1.0)))
set_two = set((PointHash(a, b, 1.0), PointHash(b, a, 1.1), PointHash(a, b, -1.0), PointHash(b, c, 1.0)))

print "common:"
for item in set_one.intersection(set_two):
    print item.p1, item.p2, item.value


#> (1.1, 2.2, 3.3) (1.0009, 2.00019, 3.0001) 1.0
#> (1.0009, 2.00019, 3.0001) (21, 22, 23) 1.0
```

As written this will require an *EXACT* match to produce the same values, you may find that you want to quantize the actual vertex values or whatever to some coarser resolution to catch near-misses too.  As written it also assumes that `PointHash(a,b, 1.0)` is not the same as `PointHash(b,a,1.0)` which may or may not be the desired behavior.

The actual hashing is done in the `__init__` method and it steals python's built-in tuple hashing which is nice and fast.

Related: http://discourse.techart.online/t/geometry-hash/3144

Comment: Nice idea with `hash`! There's an unexpected result doing `hash(-1) == hash(-2)` posted here, but there wasn't a clear explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585730/what-does-hash-do-in-python
+1

Comment: Python's default hash for -1 is -2, which is a known irritant that's now canonical and will never change....  however it's only for exactly -1, so for this application it's unlikely to be a problem

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l1 = [[[1,2], 10.], [[3, 4], 5.0]]
>>> l2 = [[[1,2], 8.], [[3, 6], 5.0]]

>>> [(v1[0] == v2[0] and v1[1] == v2[1]) for (v1,_), (v2,_) in zip(l1, l2)]
[True, False]
```

Replace integer values in `l1`, `l2` with "Points" in the above example. Obviously, this assumes that `dt.Point` objects can be compared directly.

Comment: In my particular case, the hash method was a better fit.  I will definitely keep the use of generator expressions in mind for future projects though.  -thanks